# Java mouseclick logger

Tags: java, mouse

Hi I want to build on java mouse click logger. I need to print the coordinates of mouse clicks in a file. Can you tell me how I can make this. Which APIs to use some examples or links. I need to get all the mouse clicks not only in one window.

Comment: Java is, fortunately, a particularly poor choice for writing spyware.

Comment: Do you want to log key events of your own application or globally for whole computer?

Comment: its for a program which moves the mouse. I want to log its clicks but if I can make it for whole computer will be better.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement the MouseListener interface and overwrite the mouseClicked function:

```
public class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {

   // [...]

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       System.out.println(e.getLocationOnScreen());
   }

   // [...]
}
```

Adapt that example to your needs. THe getLocationOnScreen Method returns a "Point" object which you can ask for x/y coordinates.

Comment: and from where to get the MouseEvent?

Comment: ah ok. you did not specify what kind of programm you are using (for example if you have a Swing gui or a console app or something like that).

For an application, that can react on ALL Mouse Inputs without the need of registering listener to GUI components you could take a look at the "java.awt.MouseInfo" package in the Java API.

this should provide all the functions you are asking for. 
For a very simple code example for this purpose can be found here:
http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/390-how-get-mouse-position-even-if-not-within-our-application.html

Comment: yes thank you but with this class I can't see the location when the mouse is clicked

Comment: @Ulathar  Note that 1) `MouseListener` only applies to (can only be added to) Java objects in that JVM. 2) The `MouseInfo` class will *not* provide information on mouse clicks, just location on screen.  This answer is noise..

Comment: so there is now way to get location of mouse click outside of program's window ?